wkhtml/pdfkit Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
I have a function that turns HTML pages into PDF.
        # Convert the HTML file to PDF
        options = {
            "--enable-local-file-access": None
        }
        output_pdf_file = output_pdf_path + "my_file.pdf"
        pdfkit.from_file('temp.html', output_pdf_file, options=options)

However, in some cases, I get the following error from pdfkit :
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError

Since pdfkit is just a wrapper around wkhtml. I tried running this command wkhtmltopdf temp.html teste.pdf instead:
Loading pages (1/6)
Error: Failed to load cid:96e13dc5-e1e5-485f-89ea-40daed348248, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "cid" is unknown
Error: Failed to load cid:e6ccc873-d709-4c0d-b663-36db31c3737e, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "cid" is unknown
Error: Failed to load cid:b69aed6a-0b97-4298-940b-674b355761af, with network status code 301 and http status code 0 - Protocol "cid" is unknown
Warning: SSL error ignored                                        
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                      

Those fails to load correspond to src of some ìmg tags on the HTML:
<img src="cid:96e13dc5-e1e5-485f-89ea-40daed348248"
<img src="cid:e6ccc873-d709-4c0d-b663-36db31c3737e" height="22px">

I'am wondering how to solve this... if there is anything I can do to load those img/fix this error or if I should parse the file and remove the tags.
